# How to "pip install" a package ignoring only some specific dependencies?

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, pip, dependencies

This is my problem:
I'm working on **Ubuntu** and I want to install some **packages** in a specific folder, that need to be shared later, using *pip*. I'd like to install packages ignoring some **specific** dependencies. I know that I can ignore **all** dependencies with

```
--no-deps
```

but I need to ignore just **some** of them.

For example I want to install *folium* without *numpy*, but still with other dependencies.
How can I do that? How can I **avoid just one or a list** of dependencies?

Also knowing that is not possible could be a good information.

Thanks a lot